# How can I collapse multi nested values from different levels into a single dataframe

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr, unnest

Below is an object returned from a web based dataset. It comes back as a list with a combination of object/text nesting. What I am actually doing is using reticulate to do a `source_python()` script and the conversion gives me an R object that looks like the object below.

```
# The reprex
obj = list(
  list(
    dontneed1 = "oh well",
    dontneed2 = "doesnt matter",
    values = list(
      need1 = list(list(value = "1231", 
                        text = "abc1")),
      need2 = "1232",
      need3 = "1/1/2023",
      dont_need_value = list(list(value = "12", text = "abc2")), #note that 'text' observation is needed
      need5 = list(list(value = "1234", text = "abc3")),
      need6 = list()
    )
  ),
  list(
    dontneed3 = "oh well",
    dontneed4 = "no thank you",
    values = list(
      need1 = list(list(value = "1235",
                        text = "abc4")),
      need2 = "1236",
      need3 = "1/2/2023",
      dont_need_value = list(list(value = "12", text = "abc4")), #note that 'text' observation is needed
      need5 = list(list(value = "1238", text = "abc5")),
      need6 = list()
    )
  )
)
```

Here is how I am currently cleaning the data to retain the desired tabular format (this data is then outputted as a power bi table):

```
# Extract values
new_list <- map(obj, ~.[["values"]])

# rowbind all data nested under values and then unnest
df <- data.table::rbindlist(new_list, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE, idcol = "element_number") %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(need1, dont_need_value, need5, need6))

# column bind those values and return df
# note the result output here brings in the dont_need_value observattions - the filter below            
# is needed to remove those rows
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, df)) 

# filter out the junk rows - data I actually did not need
df <- df %>% 
  filter(nchar(dont_need_value) > 2)
```

My question is - when an object comes back from a website via API retrieval and in this weird nested list format - is there a better way than above to collapse the data to a data frame and extract the 'need' variables and their observations? Note the 'dont_need_value' has an observation that is not needed but it brought a text observation with it that is needed.

Comment: What’s wrong with your current way? Does it not return what you want? Is it slow? I don’t necessarily see an error here.

Comment: Hi @jpsmith - I guess there is nothing wrong here. I'm just surprised I actually came to a solution that worked here and I guess I was just curious if my solution was optimal or if there was a better way. I'm at the stage where I am trying to understand handling more complex list structures and getting better at functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that uses `map` and `pluck`.

Note: `modify_depth()` replaces the empty lists with NAs.

```
library(tidyverse)

set_1 <- c("need1", "dont_need_value", "need5") |> set_names()
set_2 <- c("need2", "need3", "need6") |> set_names()
obj2 <- modify_depth(obj, \(x) ifelse(!length(x),NA,x), .depth=3, .ragged=T)

map(1:2, 
\(lvl1) map(set_1, \(lvl2) pluck(obj2, lvl1, "values", lvl2, 1, "text")) |> 
  bind_cols(map(set_2, \(lvl2) pluck(obj2, lvl1, "values", lvl2)))) |> 
bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thank you @andrew_reece - what would happen here if my `dput()` example was a list of 100 elements? What happens with the set_1 and set_2 logic? Do those assignments stay the same and the first argument in `map()` just changes? If that's the case what would that look like?

Would it be too much trouble to step through some of the mapping logic? I haven't seen `\(lvl1)` syntax used before for example. Is lvl1 just the 1st level of the list object? and lvlx+ would just be deeper levels? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  If it's a list with 100 elements that all have the same inner structure as your example data, then you are correct, nothing would change except for `map(1:2, ...)` becomes `map(1:100, ...)`.  Re `\(lvl1)` it is the new syntax for anonymous functions [introduced in R 4.1.0](https://www.jumpingrivers.com/blog/new-features-r410-pipe-anonymous-functions/), you could just do map(1:2, function(lvl1) ...) instead.  `lvl1` is just made up as a temporary argument, you could use `x` or whatever you want. I used `pluck` to grab elements from farther down in the nest of list elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach that applies to arbitrary levels of nesting using `rrapply()` in package `rrapply`, (extended version of base `rapply()`):

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(
  obj, 
  condition = \(x, .xname, .xparents) !grepl("dontneed", .xname) && (!is.element("dont_need_value", .xparents) || .xname != "value"), 
  how = "bind"
)
#>   values.need1.1.value values.need1.1.text values.need2 values.need3 values.dont_need_value.1.text values.need5.1.value values.need5.1.text
#> 1                 1231                abc1         1232     1/1/2023                          abc2                 1234                abc3
#> 2                 1235                abc4         1236     1/2/2023                          abc4                 1238                abc5
```

NB: the output is not exactly identical to `df` in the question, but the names/columns can be cleaned up further if necessary.